# UI Activity View Controller Showing in different language?-iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am creating an app where the user can share different forms. What is weird is when I test the app on a iPhone, the Activity View controller works fine[image]

But when I do the exact same thing on the ipad, but in a different storyboard. It does this:

[image]

Here is the code from which both of these views are getting their actions:

```
#import "FluteS.h"
#import "TUSafariActivity.h"
#import "ARChromeActivity.h"
@interface FluteS ()

@end

@implementation FluteS

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
   }
return self;
}

-(IBAction)actionButton:(id)sender;{

    NSLog(@"actionButton pressed");
    NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *filePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Flute" ofType: @"pdf"];
    NSURL *fileURL= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.friendswoodmustangband.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Flute-Audition-Scales1.pdf"];
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    NSArray *activityItems = @[fileUrl, fileURL];
    ARChromeActivity *chromeActivity = [[ARChromeActivity alloc] init];

    TUSafariActivity *TUSafari = [[TUSafariActivity alloc] init];

    NSArray *applicationActivities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:TUSafari,chromeActivity, nil];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities: applicationActivities];
    activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];


    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *filePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Flute" ofType: @"pdf"];
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I have already checked the localized part of the Info.plist, but I can't Figure out why it works on the iPhone, but not on the iPad. Does anybody have any idea what is happening?

Comment: On the iPad, run the Setting app and go to General, International. What language is selected?

Comment: English for the language.

Comment: Do you Swedish anywhere else on the iPad or in your app?

Comment: I don't believe so, but The thing is when I tested it on another iPad, it did the same thing, but only in the app(so it has to do with the app). But i don't know how or why, and it works correctly on another iPhone.

Comment: Add a log just before showing the activity view: `NSLog(@"locale = %@", [NSLocale currentLocale]);`. Add the same log in place where don't see Swedish. Also try commenting out your two custom activities and see if that has any affect.

Comment: this was the output `locale = <__NSCFLocale: 0x1e5663b0>`

Comment: Oops. Change that to: `NSLog(@"locale = %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27133/discussion-between-steve-and-rmaddy)

Comment: Ok the output for the controller showing the different language was `locale = en_US`

Answer (score 1):

When presenting the view controller, you must do so using the appropriate means for the current device. On iPad, you must present the view controller in a popover. On iPhone and iPod touch, you must present it modally.

You can use the following code for iPad.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"something"] applicationActivities:nil];
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];
self.popover.delegate = self;
[self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps you.